# Conditional Database View of Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

I have a situation here. Currently I have

- two polling tables (poll_one and poll_two) which will poll data from outside data-source. This two tables will keep interchange between each other.
- one checking table (check_poll) which tells me which tables (poll_one or poll_two) is active
- one user edit table (edit) which stores exact same columns and names as the two poll tables.

Basically I wan to create a dbview that joins the edit table and the active poll table. However, I am not sure how to do a conditional dbview to first check which polling table is active before performing my query.

I cannot use stored procedures as this dbview will be used for my hibernate mapping.

Below is a sample definition of my dbview:

```
SELECT 
CASE 
WHEN u.name IS NULL THEN p.name ELSE u.name
END AS name,

CASE 
WHEN u.size IS NULL THEN p.size ELSE u.size
END AS size,

//same for the rest of columns

FROM user_edit_table u 
LEFT JOIN poll_one p //I wan to make this conditional
ON p.id = u.id
```

Is it possible? Is there any other ways?

Thanks for all the replies,
An example is shown in the Image Below:
[image]

So based on the check table, I will choose which table I wan to left join. There is no foreign relation between the tables. All are stand alone.

Comment: can you add more details about table / foreign key relation?

Comment: **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [_Formatted_](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 2):

It's not exactly clear how the `one` or the `two` table is to be chosen but something like this should work (I assume that the `check_poll` table has a single row always):

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(p.name, u.name) AS name,
    COALESCE(p.size, u.size) AS size
FROM check_poll AS c
  CROSS JOIN user_edit_table AS u 
  LEFT JOIN poll_one AS p //I wan to make this conditional
    ON p.id = u.id
WHERE c.poll = 1        -- whatever shows which poll table to choose

UNION ALL

SELECT
    -- same list
FROM check_poll AS c
  CROSS JOIN user_edit_table u 
  LEFT JOIN poll_two p 
    ON p.id = u.id
WHERE c.poll = 2 ;
```

or even combine the two subqueries in one:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(p1.name, p2.name, u.name) AS name,
    COALESCE(p1.size, p2.size, u.size) AS size
FROM check_poll AS c
  CROSS JOIN user_edit_table AS u 
  LEFT JOIN poll_one AS p1 
    ON  p1.id = u.id
    AND c.poll = 1 
  LEFT JOIN poll_two AS p2 
    ON  p2.id = u.id
    AND c.poll = 2 ;
```